# docker problem: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I have created a test container using the latest `gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest` image. I want to execute Docker commands within this container using the permissions of the `gitlab-runner` user.

**Inside the container:**

```
root@gitlab_runner:/# su gitlab-runner
gitlab-runner@gitlab_runner:/$ id
uid=999(gitlab-runner) gid=999(gitlab-runner) groups=999(gitlab-runner)
```

Executing `docker info` results in an error:

```
gitlab-runner@gitlab_runner:/$ docker info
Client:
 Version:    24.0.5
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false

Server:
ERROR: permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/info": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
errors pretty printing info
```

When using `root` privileges, executing docker info works as expected.

**Outside the container:**

The UID 999 corresponds to the `systemd-coredump` user, which is a member of the docker group.

```
$ id systemd-coredump
uid=999(systemd-coredump) gid=999(systemd-coredump) groups=999(systemd-coredump),135(docker)
```

Docker socket permissions are as follows:

```
srw-rw----  1 root              docker    0  Oct 25 13:39 docker.sock=
```

Is there any additional configuration needed to allow the test container to correctly execute Docker commands with the permissions of the gitlab-runner user? Thank you very much!!

I have confirmed that outside the container, the user with UID 999 is indeed a member of the docker group.

Comment: It looks like in your setup the Docker socket is owned by numeric group ID 135, but that isn't one of the group IDs the user in the container has (from the first `id` command).  The host and container are isolated, and the container process can't see what groups an equivalent user on the host would have.  Do you have a [mcve] showing how you created the image and container?  (Is there a programming question here, or are you just trying to deploy GitLab?)

Comment: I added docker:x:135:gitlab-runner to /etc/group, so I can now run Docker with gitlab-runner! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I added `docker:x:135:gitlab-runner` to /etc/group, then I can now run Docker with gitlab-runner!

Answer (score 0):

This is because by default docker engine runs as root, actually there is an alternative to run docker containers as non root user ( rootless containers )

learn more : https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/